# Распознавание цифр

Tags: c#

Как распознавать цифры на изображении в c#? В общем, нужно парсить весь рабочий стол (скринить), если находим цифру "1", то принимать ее координаты и переставлять мышку на это место, с цифрой "2" и другими цифрами действия такие же.

Comment: Вы нас озадачиваете? Что сделали сами? Что не получилось?

Comment: Сделал распознавание на цвет:) Рисование в текстбоксе

Answer (score 8):

Задачка академ-уровня)))

Если сделать скриншот - легко, передвинуть мышу на координаты чуть-чуть сложнее.

То задача распознавания некого символа, причем маленького размера, причем на ляпистом изображении...

Вы попробуйте сделать руками принт-скрин своего рабочего стола и скормить это FineReader'y.
Посмотрите на жуть, которую он там распознает. А FR эту задачу уже не первый год решает))

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите [tesseract-ocr](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/).

> Движок OCR, который был разрабатывался в HP Labs в период между 1985 и 1995 годах ... и теперь в Google.

Для C# это tessnet: [Знакомство с OCR библиотекой tessnet2 (язык C#)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112599/).

Comment: > ... и теперь в Google.

Здесь не хватает грустного смайлика :(

Answer (score 1):

Подход к решению задачи изначально неверный. Всего-то требуется получить содержимое окна (рабочий стол - тоже окно). Достаточно тривиальная штука.

[Здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25925/CWindow-A-wrapper-class-for-the-window-API-functio) целый готовый класс для работы с окнами в Windows с примером использования.

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то копайте в сторону алгоритмов распознования образов.

Comment: Я уже хочу посмотреть на эту софтину)

Загогулина в том, что если там сиськи на весь экран или скажем зеленая лужайка - когда фон контрастен к надписи - то в принципе алгоритмы отработают.

А если на рабочем столе фотка типа "зимний лес" - мелкие бело-черные детали, то алгоритм там прозреет))

Comment: @SilverIce, вот это ещё один, программистский, аргумент за сиськи.